# GA - Understand why different numbers for - SEO > queries, SEO > landing pages and Organic traffic

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

Im having hard times trying to get conclusions about organic results. Data seems to not be consistent between panels.

Checking the SEO - Queries panel I have the following pic:

[image]

From the SEO - Landing page panel I have the following data after filtering the Google Property as Web:

[image]

Finally, if I get the data from the Channel > Organic > Filter: Source/Medium - google/organic I get the following:

[image]

Im interested not just in the impressions differences, which are huge as we see in the first two pictures, but also in the clicks. Clicks in SERPs are basically visits.

How can it be that one is saying 1679 clicks, another one 5571 and the visit number through Traffic channel is 6334? I know that the SEO panel works through extracting data from Webmaster Tools and Channel > Organic comes from GA. Still, the differences are huge. Why? How is this making sense?

Comment: you might want to read this: http://www.portent.com/blog/analytics/google-webmaster-tools-query-data-is-worthless.htm

Comment: @Max really interesting discussion. Are you concerned on any other news about it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is not very simple but resumes to this: The size of the data sample and the relations the data make.

If you open **Search Engine Optimization -> Queries**, you'll notice at the top the notification: Google Search: Top 1,000 daily queries and then, your data is shown as 14.46% of your total sample of about 300.000 impressions in total.
The translation for this is: your analysed sample data of 14.46% represent the top 1000 impressions of your site.

For reference, I took a look at one of my pages and my sample is 95.05% of the Total, this varies with the size of the site.

When you go to the **Search Engine Optimization -> Landing Pages** section, you are seeing the Top 1,000 daily Landing Pages, that in your case represent 12.79% of your total Landing page impressions. This doesn't have any relation with the previous Query, as you are looking at a different size sample of the same data (in this case 12.79% of the total of the impressions by your page).

The total size of Impressions in Queries is 300k and the Landing Page impressions is 500k because your page can appear more than one time for the same query, and that is not shown in the first report.

The latest image you show is the total data unfiltered, with the total amount of sessions but doesn't relate with the impressions, as it's not crossing the data with the other reports. Here, you have 100% session data coming from Organic, doesn't matter how many times user clicked or CTR's, just how many people came from this source.

**Now what sense does this make?**

1. To check the total sessions coming from Organic you go to **Acquisition -> Channels -> Organic**, in your case 6334 sessions;
2. **SEO - Queries** shows your performance for your top keywords by taking a look at a sample that not always corresponds to the total of traffic you receive from that source. If you have 6334 sessions from Organic and in this report you only see about 1600, that means the rest of your traffic comes from out of your top 1000 Queries;
3. **SEO - Landing Pages** shows your top 1000 pages that receive traffic from Organic sources. In your case you show 5571 clicks and that means that the difference to your 6334 sessions comes from landings that are out of the top 1000.